# Symfony get records from category and subcategory

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.15 with doctrine. And I have category and subcategory:

```
Category:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
      name:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Subcategory:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer() }
    name:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Category: { onDelete: CASCADE,local: category_id , foreign: id }
```

And I have product. Product has relations with category and subcategory.

```
Product:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      canUpdate: true
      fields: [name]
      builder: [myTools, StripText]
    I18n:
      fields: [name,description,shortbody,meta_keywords,meta_description]
  columns:
    partner_id:           { type: integer() }
    active:               { type: boolean, default: 0, notnull: false }
    name:                 { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    shortbody:            { type: string(500), notnull: true }
    description:          { type: string(), notnull: true }
    reference:            { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    code:                 { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    delivery_period:      { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    shipping_volume:      { type: string(100), notnull: true }    
    weight:               { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    packing:              { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    package_dimensions:   { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    type_of_packaging:    { type: string(100), notnull: true } 
    video_url:            { type: string(100), notnull: false }
    meta_keywords:        { type: string(255) }
    meta_description:     { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    Subcategory:          { local: product_id , foreign: subcategory_id, refClass: ProductSubcategory } 
    Category:             { local: product_id , foreign: category_id, refClass: ProductCategory } 
    Partner:              { local: partner_id , foreign: id, onDelete: CASCADE }



ProductSubcategory:
  connection: doctrine
  columns:
    subcategory_id:  { type: integer(), primary: true}
    product_id:      { type: integer(), primary: true }
  relations:
    Product:         {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: product_id, foreign: id }
    Subcategory:     {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: subcategory_id, foreign: id }

ProductCategory:
  connection: doctrine
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer(), primary: true}
    product_id:   { type: integer(), primary: true }
  relations:
    Product:             {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: product_id, foreign: id }
    Category:            {  onDelete: CASCADE,local: category_id, foreign: id }
```

So I need to get all products from subcategory and category(one query for it)
I can get all product that belongs to category:

```
 $q = $this->createQuery('a')
                       ->andWhere('a.active=1')
                       ->leftJoin('a.ProductCategory o')
                       ->andWhere('o.Category_id=?',$category_id)
                       ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC');
```

But I do not now how to get all product from all subcategories of category....Thank you!

Comment: in your schema is - if you get all products with Category, then you have also all products of subcategories in this Category. If not please add simply fixtures, what do you want make?

Comment: I can get all products from category, but I can not get all products from all subcategory of category.I need one query for it.

Comment: please add fixtures and example. your query should be so work.

Comment: Thank you! I solve this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) are you aware of the NestedSet behaviour in Doctrine? This should solve the need for your `Subcategory` table. And it also allows for "deeper categories"

2) In your current model, *why* does `Product` have a relation to both `Subcategory` and `Category`? The `Category` can be determined by the `Subcategory`.

If you fix one of these, it will be a lot easier to implement your query.

Comment: **2** - In the beginning was "The Category can be determined by the Subcategory."but customers said that they want to remake category and subcategory in this way(They said it after the project was on production),we have long denied them, but...(**1** - I have no time remake category and subcategory:-(